# Is there a name for a text input that lets a user input multiple values?

Tags: mobile, input-fields, input, webforms

There is a type of text input that allows the user to enter an array of items, sometimes with autocomplete, usually adding a new "item" to the list either whenever the user presses space and/or enter. Once an item is entered, it typically goes to the right of the list with a little 'x' by it to quick-delete it if desired.

One example is SE's own "tag" input field:

[image: SE tag input]
<sup>SE 'tag' input</sup>

[image: jira input field]
<sup>Another example (from Jira)</sup>

Is there a common name for this sort of input? I'm working on a Flutter app where I'd like to use something like this; knowing what it's called would help me Google around to see if someone has already implemented a nice pre-made widget for this purpose. My closest guess is "multiple text input" or "array text input" neither of which really turn up anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Material Design, they're called [Input Chips](https://material.io/components/chips#types). They're driven by terms entered into a text field.